# Flask-Security access Login Manager

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I'm working to develop a flask application. I've settled on using Flask-Security for a lot of the great features it has. However I'm having a hard time finding examples of working code beyond the QuickStart they give [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/index.html). Specifically, I need to access the login manager from the Flask-Login plugin which I know that Flask-Security uses. Does this mean I need to import Login-Manager from Flask-Security? What's the best way to access this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Flask-security-example](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security-example) repository?

Comment: Yep. It's pretty much the same thing as the QuickStart.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: when you let flask-security handle the login it automatically establishes all this. you may not realize it but all that is done in the background for both login & logout. you have access to the full suite of flask-login functions for a logged in account (and anonymous also).

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, you can access the login manager via:

```
current_app.login_manager
```

From the example I see in the Flask-Security docs (http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html), it probably responds to the native Flask-Login methods found in that module's docs:

https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#api-documentation

I'm just starting to tinker with Flask-Security myself, and am also annoyed with the lack of examples and documentation, so forgive me if this doesn't help ><

Comment: Found a tiny example for `current_app.login_manager` in the docs: [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html#protecting-views).